# Clicking on notification doesn't open Android app

Tags: android, firebase, onesignal

I am using onesignal and firebase to push notifications from wordpress blog to Android app and when I click on notification that just arrived, application will open only if it run in the background. If it is completely closed, clicking on notification will do nothing. How do I achieve clicking on notification opens app even if app is not in the background opened?

Below is the code that handles notifications:

```
 class nyonNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalnyon", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }

            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
                Log.i("OneSignalnyon", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

            // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.
            // Replace - getApplicationContext() - with any Android Context.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the intent flags?

Comment: I have just tried, still not opening app if it's completely closed.

Comment: pending intent ?

Comment: @notTdar what about pending intent?

Comment: don't you need pending intent for opening activity,service..during notification buillding

Comment: @notTdar it works like shown in the code, notifications are sent and clicking on them opens app when app is in the background, otherwise it doesn't open app.

Answer (score 3):

The code which I am using for opening app on the click of notification, which is working perfectly fine :

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
 resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 //if you want to send some data
 resultIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION, data);
```

Now you have to create PendingIntent
PendingIntent:  As per docs by creating pending intent means you are granting it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other application was yourself. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );
```

Now when you are creating your Notification set this pending intent setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) to that notification.

```
  Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(System.currentTimeMillis() + ""))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .build();
```

Comment: I was making mistake on "PendingIntent.getBroadcast" instead I have to use "PendingIntent.getActivity" :) I commented on this just in case someone is facing an issue like me.

Answer (score 1):

Well to solve this problem, first thing is to read documentation more clearly (what I didn't do) so here it is:

> By default OneSignal will open or resume your launcher Activity when a notification is tapped on. You can disable this behavior by adding the meta-data tag **com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT** set to **DISABLE** inside your application tag in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Make sure that you register it inside android manifest, e.g.:

```xml
    <application ...>
       <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
    </application>
```

Create handler for opened notifications, e.g.:

```java
public class MyNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

    private final Context context;

    public MyNotificationOpenedHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

        if (result.action.type == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.Opened) {
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }

            String category = data.optString("category", null);

            if (category == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (category.equals("global")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next point is:

> Make sure you are initializing **OneSignal** with **setNotificationOpenedHandler** in the **onCreate** method in your **Application** class. You will need to call **startActivity** from this callback.

You'll need to extend **Application** class, e.g.:

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler(getApplicationContext()))
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
    }
}
```

Set application name inside android manifest, e.g.:

```xml
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And you're ready to handle notifications when app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Set "**setNotificationOpenedHandler**"

```
   OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler())
            .init();
```

Add this class to your launcher activity ( make sure notification have "additionalData" )

```
 public class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        //OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;
        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("Data", null);
            if (customKey != null)
            {
                Log.d("LOGGED", "notificationOpened: " +  customKey);
                if(customKey.equals("Notification"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value is : " + customKey, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

More Info 
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-

Comment: Read the question before answering it. I used the code from documentation. You just pasted the same thing.

Comment: as far i remember when i posted this, there isn't the snippet code in question. Don't know, maybe i overlooked. NeverMind. :)
But this is working for my end.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml to prevent the launching of your main Activity

```
 <application ...>
      <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
    </application>
```